# Flutter: Space between Objects/Center and Column don't work: Too many positional arguments

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm a flutter-newie and I'm building my first App.
My Problem: I wanted to add some placeholder for Icons (I havent finished them), that's no problem, but I don't know how to add in space beetween them.
I wanted to center them, but than this appears:

> Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.
>   Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments.

Can someone help me?
Here's my code (only app-body):

```
body:
    Container(   [<--- Here Bug "("]
      Center(    [<--- Here Bug "("]
       Column(
          children: <Widget> [
             Row(
              children: <Widget> [
                Placeholder( 
                  color: Colors.deepOrange,
                  strokeWidth: 3.5,
                  fallbackWidth: 75.0,
                  fallbackHeight: 75.0,
               ),

               Placeholder( 
                  color: Colors.indigo,
                  strokeWidth: 3.5,
                  fallbackWidth: 75.0,
                  fallbackHeight: 75.0,
                ),

                Placeholder( 
                  color: Colors.pink[200],
                  strokeWidth: 3.5,
                  fallbackWidth: 75.0,
                  fallbackHeight: 75.0,
                ),
              ],
               ),


               Row(
                children: <Widget> [
                  Placeholder( 
                   color: Colors.black,
                    strokeWidth: 3.5,
                   fallbackWidth: 75.0,
                   fallbackHeight: 75.0,
                ),

                 Placeholder( 
                   color: Colors.blueGrey[300],
                   strokeWidth: 3.5,
                   fallbackWidth: 75.0,
                   fallbackHeight: 75.0,
                ),

               Placeholder( 
                  color: Colors.red,
                 strokeWidth: 3.5,
                 fallbackWidth: 75.0,
                 fallbackHeight: 75.0,
                ),
               ],
              ),
            ],
          ),


     ),
 ),
```

[Screenshot (App)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WAlc.jpg)

Thx in advance! ^^

Comment: Container must have child, Center must have child. You just inserted the widgets without telling it what is child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use named arguments, with the name `child`:

```
body:
  Container(
    child: Center(
      child: Column(
```

Positional arguments are arguments that don't have a name, such as `child` but rely on their position. Named arguments require a name and their position doesn't matter.

In this case `Container` and `Center` have a named argument `child` that should be used to specify the next Widget in the tree. Just like `Column` has the named argument `children`.